# Use div as a dropdown menu overlapping other contents?

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu, hidden

Is there any way for me to use a div as a dropdown menu positio exactly like [this](http://i49.tinypic.com/16bk861.png)? I already tried absolute position but it doesn't work with other screen size. What I want is for it to work on all screen resolutions. I tried using tables(hiding the td and showing it on hover)but the menu just pushes the contents below it. I desperately need to get this sorted out I've been working on it for weeks now and still not even close to what I want. Thank you in advance.

What I tried so far:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hover-here").hover(function(){
     $("#boxed-menu-div").toggle();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#boxed-menu-div{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 246px;
 }
```

This works perfectly only on my screen resolution. I used relative positioning but it only pushes the contents below. Is there any other alternatives to what absolute can do?

Comment: of course there is, but please include some code in your example.

Comment: Please share some code, that would help.

Comment: Please share what you've already tried.

Comment: You want to use [relative positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: Here is my code: `jQuery("#button-to-be-hovered").hover(function(){jQuery("#boxed-menu-div").toggle();});` and the css: `#boxed-menu-div{display:none;}`

Comment: I also tried `#boxed-menu-div{display: none; position: absolute; top: 100px; right; 246px;}` This works perfectly on my screen size but not on others. I was thinking of using `<select>` and `<option>` but I can't modify it to look like [link](http://i49.tinypic.com/16bk861.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... First things first. Tables are a definite no and you don't need jQuery either.

You have four html elements that combined are designed to do this specific task.

These are `<nav>`, `<ul>` `<li>` and `<a>`. Now I'm making an assumption here that since you want it to work on all screen sizes then you are wanting this to be responsive, I'm also assuming that since you want rounded corners, gradients, shadows etc then you will be aiming for modern browsers, ie9+ and the others.

Bearing that in mind here would be the html I would use to create a menu.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

The css would go something like this. Please note that I have only created a very rough approximation of what you are after.

```css
body{
    /* Set the overall font*/
    font-family:arial, serif;
}

/* Contain floats: h5bp.com/q */
nav > ul:before, nav > ul:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

nav > ul:after {
    clear: both;
}

nav > ul {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* Level one */
nav > ul > li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    width:30%;
    max-width:100px;
}
nav > ul > li > a{
    padding:.5em 1em;
}

/* Level 2*/
nav > ul > li > ul {
    background:#666;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    padding:1em;
    width:200px; /*set to whatever you need*/
    display:none;
}

/* Second list on level 2*/
nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > ul{
    margin-left:-50%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Last list on level 2*/
nav > ul > li:last-child > ul{
    right:0;
    border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Hover level 1*/
nav > ul > li:hover {
    background:#666;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color:#fff;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a,
nav > ul > li > ul a{
    color:#fff;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
```

I've included a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJppp/) for you to play with. As you can see this will work from mobile-up. Fullscreen link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QJppp/embedded/result/) resize to see it working.

Comment: Man you are a god! I'm going to try that now for I'm very close to deadline. Thank you so much!

Comment: I also want to vote up to your answer but my reputation is too low to allowed to do that. lolz

Comment: Cheers! :) Happy to help. I would recommend making a point when you can of really starting from the basics and learning why things work the way they do. It really makes css much easier once you know that. The rest is just frills really.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without seeing your code.

I can only suggest to use css menu.

```
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
        <div class="sub-nav">
            Anything
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#main-nav {height: 25px; list-style-type: none;}
#main-nav li {position: relative; float: left; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; margin: 0 15px 0 0;}

.sub-nav {display: none; position: absolute; width: 400px; top: 25px; left: 0; z-index: 999; background: #f2f2f2;}

#main-nav li:hover .sub-nav {display: block;}
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/ELyQW/2/